# By using this BST insertion method I have only root as output,why?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I am trying to insert in a binary search tree using recursion and then print it preorderly using this specific code, but I have only root as output,why?Is this because each time stack(after each call) is popping off thus removing new nodes?(This is a java code)

```
class node{
    int data;
    node left;
    node right;
    node(int key){
        data = key;
        left = right = null;
    }
}

class bst{
    node  root;
    node  temp;
    node  last;
    bst(){
        root =  null;
    }
    bst(int key){
        root = new node(key);
    }
    void Insert(node r,int value){
        temp = r;
        if(temp == null){
            if(root == null){
                root = new node(value);
                root.data = value;
                return;
            }
            temp = new node(value);
            temp.data = value;
            return;
        }
        else{
            if(value > temp.data){
                Insert(temp.right,value);
                return;
            }
            else{
                Insert(temp.left,value);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

class test{
        static void in_order(node root){
            if(root == null){
                return;
            }
            in_order(root.left);
            System.out.println(root.data+" ");
            in_order(root.right);
        }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        bst tree = new bst();
        tree.Insert(tree.root,45);
        tree.Insert(tree.root,39);
        tree.Insert(tree.root,12);
        tree.Insert(tree.root,59);
        test.in_order(tree.root);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are only getting a single integer for an output is because the first `Insert` call correctly adds the element to the tree, but subsequent calls fail because you overwrite the data member `temp` to `null` when you recursively insert to the left or right. Thus the second branch of your first `if` statement never gets executed.

You don't actually need the variable `temp` here. A common convention is to have a private, recursive member function that takes the root of the tree as a parameter returns the modified tree, and assign the return value to `root` in a public member function.

```
public void Insert(int value) {
  root = Insert(root, value);
}

private node Insert(node r, int value) {
  if (r == null) {
    r = new node(value);
  }
  else if (value > r.data) {
    r.right = Insert(r.right, value);
  }
  else {
    r.left = Insert(r.left, value);
  }
  return r;
}
```

This means that you only have to call it like `tree.Insert(x)`.

Comment: No, actually I do not think that overwrite is causing a problem in here...
Actually when I try to add three nodes as 45 39 12 by three insert call than what happens is that,
45 is set to root as I am always calling with the root node....
But when I try insert(39) then it adds node 39 to the left side of 45..
Then when I try insert(12) then its says 45 nodes left side is null...
why this is happening? overwrite? no dude...
when I called insert(39) it actually added node 39 to the left of 45 temporarily.. Then the stack pops of and my 39 node goes to garbage thus null.so I cant add 12.

Comment: But what annoys me is that temp is not local to the recursive method insertion... So it should definitely hold those nodes.. Whats really happening here I need to find out...

Comment: You can see in your code you are always returning the root so that the root doesn't get popped of simultaneously adding nodes to the root.... Also you set root as not local....

Comment: I think in your code in first if block you should return...
Your left and right nodes never sets

Comment: @MohammedDilshad When you do `Insert(temp.right)` and `Insert(temp.left)` this will constantly reset `temp` to `null` when you do `temp = r`. Besides, doing `temp = r` and then `temp = new node(value)` has 0 effect on `r`. `temp = new node(value)` makes `temp` point to an entirely different tree. Therefore, the tree pointed to by `temp` only ever has a single node (just like `root`). Also, yes I could have returned in that `if` statement. It doesn't make a difference weather I returned there or not though.

Comment: @MohammedDilshad Nope, it doesn't. Did *you* try running it? It compiles fine whether it's in the `if` block or its the last line like in my code.

Comment: @MohammedDilshad No problem. And don't worry, when I was learning recursion, where to put the return statement was always a source of confusion. :)

Comment: No no please don't mind, Beg you pardon for my such ignorant act...
You are a best coder.....

Comment: "when I was learning recursion, where to put the return statement was always a source of confusion. :) "-so I am not alone thanks...